# Prevent hiding of ModalPopupExtender when ok or cancel is clicked

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax

I am using an ASP.NET `ModalPopupExtender` on a page and would like to prevent the dialog from hiding when the user presses the ok button in certain conditions.  But I can't seem to find a way.

What I am looking for is something like this

```
ajax:ModalPopupExtender
...
OnOkScript="return confirm('You sure?')"
...
```

if confirm is false, then the modal dialog doesn't disappear.

Comment: Kind of looks like I need to add my own buttons, and not hook up the OkControlID and CancelControlID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding in your specific situation you would not wire up the button, and just wire up a script to handle the conditional, then you can close it via JS.

Answer (score 1):

The following JavaScript function will allow you to achieve this:

```
function conditionalHide(clientID)
{
    if (confirm('You sure?'))
    {
        $find(clientID).hide();
    }
}
```

You can wire this up to your asp:Button control in the `Page_Load` event of your page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        btnOK.OnClientClick = string.Format("conditionalHide('{0}'); return false;",
            panPopup_ModalPopupExtender.ClientID);
    }
}
```

Some notes:

- `panPopup_ModalPopupExtender` is your ModalPopupExtender
- The `return false;` prevents a postback from occurring when the user clicks the button
- You could hard-code the `ClientID` of the ModalPopupExtender, but this introduces an (additional) maintainance headache. The approach shown is the best one that I've found to alleviate this overhead